# Build specific modules in Qt6 (i.e. QtMqtt)

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt6

For a project which uses MQTT, I always had to compile the QtMqtt module from source, because it wasn't included in the prebuilt windows release and couldn't be chosen for installation either. In Qt5 that was pretty easy: Download source code from official git (https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtmqtt.git/), open the .pro file in QtCreator and compile the project. For installation, I just moved the .dll files to my Qt install directory.

Now in Qt6, the build process was switched from qmake to cmake, so I cannot simply load the project in QtCreator, but have to compile it manually using CMake, which I find really unintuitive and prone to errors. From what I understand, I cannot compile single modules on their own from now on, but have to get the whole Qt 6.2.0 source code instead (i.e. via installer option) and then use a `--target` option on CMake to build only specific module. So here is what I did so far:

1. Get Qt source code from installer (installed to `Qt/6.2.0/Src`)
2. Create a command line environment according to [this manual](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/windows-building.html)
3. Open cmd environment, navigate to build folder (i.e. `Qt/6.2.0/build`)
4. Configure build using command: `..\Src\configure -prefix Qt\6.2.0\build`
5. Build with cmake using command `cmake --build . --target qtmqtt`
6. Install using command `cmake --install .`

What happens, is that the configuration works, and the build supposedly too, but installation fails with something like:

```
CMake Error at qtbase/src/3rdparty/libpng/cmake_install.cmake:41 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot find
  "F:/DEV/prog/Qt/6.2.0/build/qtbase/mkspecs/modules/qt_ext_libpng.pri": File
  exists.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/src/3rdparty/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  qtbase/src/cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
  qtbase/cmake_install.cmake:244 (include)
  cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
```

The folder `Qt/6.2.0/build` then only consists of .cmake files but nothing which seems to be usable .dll files for me. I just don't understand how to properly set up everything with cmake. Why would they make it so complicated after all now, as it was fairly easy to compile modules with qmake in Qt5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand, I cannot compile single modules on their own
> from now on, but have to get the whole Qt 6.2.0 source code instead
> (i.e. via installer option)

That's not correct. Given a pre-built Qt, you should be still able to just build  the qmqtt package from source by running e.g.

```
<QTDIR>\bin\qt-configure-module <mqtt_src_dir>
cmake --build .
```

Answer (score 6):

Having Qt 6.6.0 installed in `${HOME}/Qt/6.6.0/` using the Qt Installer, this is how I did it on Linux.

### Detailed steps:

```
# Create a work directory
mkdir ~/temporal && cd ~/temporal

# Clone the repository
git clone https://github.com/qt/qtmqtt.git

# Switch to the repository
cd qtmqtt

# Checkout the branch corresponding to the target kit
git checkout 6.6.0

# Create a directory to build the module cleanly
mkdir build && cd build

# Use the qt-configure-module tool 
~/Qt/6.6.0/gcc_64/bin/qt-configure-module ..

# Build it here
~/Qt/Tools/CMake/bin/cmake --build .

# Install the module in the correct location 
~/Qt/Tools/CMake/bin/cmake --install . --verbose
```

### Testing on a clean project:

**Edit the project's `CMakeLists.txt` file**

(1) Add `Mqtt` to the relevant `find_package` macro like this:

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 COMPONENTS Widgets Network Sql Mqtt REQUIRED)
```

(2) Add `Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Mqtt` to a `target_link_libraries` line like this:

```
 target_link_libraries(MyCleanProject PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Network Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Mqtt  Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Sql)
```

(3) Run CMake

**Try actually using the module**

Add relevant includes in the project source like this:

```
#include <QtMqtt/QtMqtt>

// and then try to use QtMqtt classes
QMqttClient client;
```

**Rebuild the project. Should compile and link cleanly.**

### Addendum

It's desirable to have proper environment variables set while building Qt projects from the CLI. My preference is to have a script in my user directory with all the relevant variables.

### My `Qt_environment.sh`:

```
export QT_VERSION="6.6.0"

export QT_INSTALL_DIR="${HOME}/Qt"
export CMAKE_BIN_DIR="${QT_INSTALL_DIR}/Tools/CMake/bin"
export QMAKE_BIN_DIR="${QT_INSTALL_DIR}/${QT_VERSION}/gcc_64/bin"
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="${QT_INSTALL_DIR}/${QT_VERSION}/gcc_64/"
export NINJA_DIR="${QT_INSTALL_DIR}/Tools/Ninja"
export PATH="${PATH}:${CMAKE_BIN_DIR}:${QMAKE_BIN_DIR}:${NINJA_DIR}"
```

One can choose to load manually from the command line before building a project like this

```
source $HOME/Qt_environment.sh
# do some Qt stuff here, cmake, ninja, etc
```

or simply have it loaded from `.bashrc` for every new bash shell. The same can be accomplished for any other shell.

```
# $HOME/.bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

# ...
# rest of the .bashrc file ommited for brevity
# ...

# Relevant part here - add these two lines at the end
# Load Qt environment variables
source "$HOME/Qt_environment.sh"
```

### Notes on building with Qt 6.5.0

I found an issue while trying to build `QtMqtt` for Qt 6.5.0, which looks like the following:

```
/home/user/Qt/6.5.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qfloat16.h:81:42: error:
  declaration of ‘f’ shadows a member of ‘qfloat16’ [-Werror=shadow]

     81 |     constexpr inline qfloat16(NativeType f) : f(f) {}
        |                               ~~~~~~~~~~~^

/home/user/Qt/6.5.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qfloat16.h:121:20: note:
  shadowed declaration is here

    121 |         NativeType f;
        |                    ^

  cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

It's possible to resolve the warning/error by editing `${QT_DIR}/6.5.0/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qfloat16.h` by modifying the name of the constructor parameter to anything different than `f`, which clashes and shadows the member variable with the same `f` name.

from this:

```
   constexpr inline qfloat16(NativeType f) : f(f) {}
```

to this:

```
   constexpr inline qfloat16(NativeType ff) : f(ff) {}
```

Note that this is not a blanket solution for all warnings/errors of this kind:

`declaration of ‘zzz’ shadows a member of ‘whateverType’ [-Werror=shadow].`

Comment: Thank you for this post, but I am facing a problem.
`xpress_embedo@hp:~/Work/Qt/DontCommit/qtmqtt/build$ /opt/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/bin/qt-configure-module ..`
I am getting the error.
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/xpress_embedo/Work/Qt/DontCommit/qtmqtt/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
CMake Error at /opt/Qt/6.2.4/gcc_64/lib/cmake/Qt6/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:957 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.

Comment: Maybe you need to set proper environment variables. Will update my answer with that in mind.

Comment: @xpress_embedo added a note at the end of the answer

Comment: @dsculz Thank You very much, it works.
Another similar solution is to build the project using Qt Creator and then install the library using the command you have mentioned "~/Qt/Tools/CMake/bin/cmake --install . --verbose" +1

Comment: yes, Qt Creator does that for you and as you say, it's another option

Answer (score 0):

try to replace `cmake --install .` with `cmake --install qtmqtt`